# Jython - Saving output of script which has Korean string to a file

Tags: java, file, utf-8, jython, jython-2.7

I tried to execute a simple Python script which has a Korean string.
When I tried to write the output of this execution to a file, the Korean string is not printed correctly.

```
PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter() {
    {
        cflags = new CompilerFlags(CompilerFlags.PyCF_SOURCE_IS_UTF8);
    }
};
String outputPath = "C:\\views\\mithun.txt";
interp.setOut(new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputPath), "UTF-8")));
String execScript = "abc = '헬로우'\r\n" +                 
                    "print \"Printing Korean : \", abc";
interp.exec(execScript);
```

Here is what I see in file opened in Notepad++ with utf-8 encoding:

[image: Notepad++ screenshot]

Comment: Hi Mithun, welcome :)
I'm not entirely familiar with this subject.
Help me: is utf-8 able to encode korean characters

Comment: Hi @WurmD, Thanks a lot! :) Yes it is able to encode utf-8, if I don't add interp.setOut and let the output to print on Console.. Its printing the Korean correctly.